# How to set both gravity and layout gravity of a LinearLayout programatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, gravity, layout-gravity

I am risking writing a duplicate question, but as I was researching the answer to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558289/get-linearlayout-gravity), I realized that I couldn't find a simple question and answer that included setting both gravity and layout_gravity of a `LinearLayout`. Also, I was confused as to the difference between them when talking about a `ViewGroup` rather than just a view. I am answering my question below.

Here are some of the other questions I viewed:

- [How to set gravity to layout programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211166/how-to-set-gravity-to-layout-programmatically)
- [Set gravity for LinearLayout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223374/set-gravity-for-linearlayout-programmatically)
- [android - setting LayoutParams programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678785/android-setting-layoutparams-programmatically)
- [LayoutParams gravity not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708151/layoutparams-gravity-not-working)
- [layout_gravity in LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783896/layout-gravity-in-linear-layout)
- [Problem with setLayoutParams method in android UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948914/problem-with-setlayoutparams-method-in-android-ui)
- [how to set setLayoutParams for linear layout elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715612/how-to-set-setlayoutparams-for-linear-layout-elements)
- [Is it possible to change the layout width and height in Android at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151056/is-it-possible-to-change-the-layout-width-and-height-in-android-at-run-time)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Short answer

Set gravity

```
linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Set layout gravity

```
// the LinearLayout's parent is a FrameLayout      
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(400, 400);
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP|Gravity.RIGHT;
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

### Background

Previously, [I have explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26190050/3681880) the difference between 'gravity' and `layout_gravity' for views within a layout.

Setting the `gravity` of a `LinearLayout` itself changes the location of the views within it. Setting the layout_gravity of a `LinearLayout` changes how the `LinearLayout` is arranged within its parent layout.

This image shows a `LinearLayout` (brown) within a `FrameLayout` (white). The `LinearLayout`'s `gravity` is set to `center_horizontal` and its `layout_gravity` is set to `right|bottom`.

[image]

Here is the xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llExample"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:background="#e3e2ad"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#bcf5b1"
            android:text="TextView 1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#aacaff"
            android:text="TextView 2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

### Changing things programmatically

The following code shows how to change both the `gravity` and the `layout_gravity` of the `LinearLayout`.

```
public class LinearLayoutGravity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.linear_layout_gravity);

        // Change the gravity (not layout_gravity) of the LinearLayout
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llExample);
        ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        // Change the layout_gravity (not gravity) of the LinearLayout      
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(400, 400);
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP|Gravity.RIGHT;
        ll.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

### See also

- [`RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout` with gravity: What is the effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42153928/3681880)

Comment: Perfect Answer. You made my day.

Answer (score 2):

**If you are using KOTLIN use `or` operator like this:**

```
GRAVITY = Gravity.RIGHT or Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL

frameContainer.layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                     FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                     GRAVITY)
```