# Align imageview to bottom right in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-framelayout

I am using below code to align imageview to bottom right with margin of 20,10 inside FrameLayout but it is appearing at top left.Where am I going wrong?

```
 ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(refreshBtn.getLayoutParams());
    marginParams.setMargins(0, 0, 20, 10);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
layoutParams.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.BOTTOM;
refreshBtn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Could you post more of your code? Specifically, the xml you are working with?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are changing the layout gravity, meaning that you are positioning the FrameLayout in the bottom right corner. However, it's possible that the FrameLayout is filling the whole screen in which case the layout gravity doesn't really change anything. Imagine a book perfectly fitting in a drawer. No matter how you're holding the drawer, the book doesn't move inside it.

What you have to do is use the "setGravity()" method of the FrameLayout itself. This will change the actual gravity inside the FrameLayout.

Source:
[How to set both gravity and layout gravity of a LinearLayout programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086486/how-to-set-both-gravity-and-layout-gravity-of-a-linearlayout-programatically/27086487#27086487)

Comment: My framelayout consists of many views and i want to position only this imageview to bottom right

Comment: Are you sure you want to put the ImageView into the bottom right corner programatically then? Putting it into the bottom right corner would be easier with XML.

Comment: Yes i have to change margin pogrammatically as per the requirement

Comment: Can't you define the ImageView's layout gravity in the XML but set the margin programatically?